# In meteor How do I create a multichatroom app with unique urls for different rooms?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I've got the basic chatroom working (single page), but I'd like to generate a unique one when I browse to my URL. E.g. User browses to chatroom.com and is redirected to chatrooom.com/room1, then s/he can share that url with friends to chat with. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a router, you could use backbone or my personal favorite meteor router (installed via [meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite)):

```
mrt install router
```

in your client js

```
//In your chat query add something to localise your chat messages for your room e.g (if you're using handlebars):

Template.messages.message = function() {
    //assuming messages contains your collection of chats
    return messages.find({room:Session.get("room")}) //get the room name set in the router
};
```

And for your router (also in the client js):

```
Meteor.Router.add({
  '/': 'home',
  '/rooms/:id': function(id) {
     Session.set("room",id); //set the room for the template
     return "messages"; //If you're template is called messages
  },
  '*': 'not_found'
```

});

So if you were to load `/rooms/lobby` it would load only the messages with the `room` value as `lobby`.

More docs on meteor router here : https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router

Comment: @Akshat This (and many others!) are great answers.  Jade's looking for you -- could you drop her a line at contact@meteor.com?